# Dask takes too long to load and process 100 GB file

Tags: python, bigdata, dask, bioinformatics

I wanted to load two files (4.7 GB and 126 GB). The 126 GB file has lot of redundant data, so I'm using a regular expression match to remove the data. After this, I'm merging these files by 5 columns. I'm using dask to load, clean-up and merge my data, but when I run the code, it stalls and doesn't finish.

My Jupyter notebook code is as follows

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
import pandas as pd
import os

client = Client()
client
annotated = dd.read_table("small_file",low_memory=False)
pat_details = dd.read_table("big_file",low_memory=False)
# Replacing headers in big_file
headers = []
with open("headers","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        headers.append(line.strip("\n"))

pat_details.columns = headers

# Replace ref variant calls with null - reduces data size quite significantly (Shrinks data to roughly 10%)
pat_slim = pat_details.replace(to_replace='^[.|0][\/\:][.|0].*',value="",regex=True)

# Change data types so merging can be done
annotated['Chr'] = annotated['Chr'].astype(str)
annotated['Start'] = annotated['Start'].astype(int)
annotated['End'] = annotated['End'].astype(int)
annotated['Ref'] = annotated['Ref'].astype(str)
annotated['Alt'] = annotated['Alt'].astype(str)

pat_slim['Chr'] = pat_slim['Chr'].astype(str)
pat_slim['Start'] = pat_slim['Start'].astype(int)
pat_slim['End'] = pat_slim['End'].astype(int)
pat_slim['Ref'] = pat_slim['Ref'].astype(str)
pat_slim['Alt'] = pat_slim['Alt'].astype(str)

# Merging the two files together, indicator to check if all rows were matched
combined = dd.merge(annotated, pat_slim,how="outer",on=['Chr','Start','End','Ref','Alt'],indicator=True)

merged = combined.compute()
merged.to_parquet("merged_data")
```

I tried it on a toy example having 1000 lines and it worked fine. However, when I tried to read the actual data I got the following error -

```
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 14% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 14% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 14% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
distributed.utils_perf - WARNING - full garbage collections took 14% CPU time recently (threshold: 10%)
..... and so on
```

While there was a warning, the data was loaded up. When I used `compute` I got the following error -

```
distributed.worker - ERROR - Worker stream died during communication: tcp://127.0.0.1:33033
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 218, in connect
    _raise(error)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/core.py", line 203, in _raise
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Timed out trying to connect to 'tcp://127.0.0.1:33033' after 10 s: connect() didn't finish in time

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

And after a lot of these error I got these types of error -

```
distributed.worker - WARNING - gc.collect() took 8.032s. This is usually a sign that some tasks handle too many Python objects at the same time. Rechunking the work into smaller tasks might help.
distributed.worker - WARNING - gc.collect() took 6.040s. This is usually a sign that some tasks handle too many Python objects at the same time. Rechunking the work into smaller tasks might help..
```

The task ran for 12 + hours so I terminated it. This [github page](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/2068) mentions similar issue as mine, but so far I've not been able to wrap my head around the issue. My server has 56 threads and ~370 GB memory, and the max memory utilization was 100GB, so not sure if it could be the same issue or not.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I recommend using the unix tool 'sed' for this

Comment: sed was greedy based on my matching, I went with an AWK solution. Running it on the data now, though I guess this too will take time unless I split the file and run it in parallel.

Comment: For context, awk took around 3 hours to parse the 110GB file. I might split the file using gnu parallel and see if that improves speed. My data is on RAID5 with HDDs, so let me see how much gains I get. Pandas took around an hour to merge the two files and write it to a tsv file.